# Can I choose the distance in Scikit K means clusterization?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

I have generated a clusterization using [K means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) in Python's [Sci kit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) using the following code.

```
clustering=KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusterss, max_iter=300)
clustering.fit(data_state_normalized)
```

This has been straightforward and it works as intended.

As far as I know, Kmeans works by calculating the distances between the centroid of the cluster and its elements, and I assume that this distance is euclidean.

I am interested in the calculation of K means using other distances such as [Manhattan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cityblock.html). However, I cannot find how to do this in the documentation of K means. I know that this can be done in [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) by defining an object as

```
class DBScan:

    def __init__(self, distance='cityblock'):
        self.distance = distance

    def find_distance(self, x, type='cityblock'):
        return distance.squareform(distance.pdist(x, type))

    def fit_predict(self, data):
        if self.distance == 'cityblock':
            data_dist = self.find_distance(data, type='cityblock')
        else:
            data_dist = self.find_distance(data, type='euclidean')
        return DBSCAN(eps=15, min_samples=2, metric='precomputed').fit_predict(data_dist)
```

and then

```
dbscan_instance = DBScan()
clusters = dbscan_instance.fit_predict(data_state_normalized)
```

[Hierarchical clusering](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html) allows this as well as:

```
  Clustering_Jerarquico=linkage(data_state_normalized, 'median', metric='cityblock')
    dendrogram =sch.dendrogram(Clustering_Jerarquico)
clusters=fcluster(Clustering_Jerarquico, t=15, criterion="distance")
```

So I am convinced that it can be done as well for K means. Can someone please point me if I am right?